# gcc seems to compile my code wrong?

Tags: c, gcc

I am rather new in C and i was trying to solve some exercises in my textbook and encountered a wierd Problem. although my Task is undeniably easy the program just wont work right. after some Trials it seems that the fault is on the Compiler but as much as this sounds unreasonable its the only justification i can bring up

without any further delay here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

double power(double n, int p);

int main(void)
{
double x, xpow;
int exp;

printf("Enter a number and the positive integer power");
printf(" to which\nthe number will be raised. Enter q");
printf(" to quit.\n");
while (scanf("%lf%d", &x, &exp) == 2)
{
    xpow = power(x,exp);
    printf("%.3g to the power %d is %.5g\n", x, exp, xpow);
    printf("Enter next pair of numbers or q to quit.\n");
}
printf("Hope you enjoyed this power trip -- bye!\n");

return 0;
}

double power(double n, int p)
{
double pow = 1;
int i ;

if ( n == 0 && p == 0)
{
    printf("0 to zeroth power is undefined\nwe will use therefor 1 instead\n");
    p = 1 ;
}

if (p >= 0)
{
    for (i = 1 ; i <= p ; i++);
        pow *= n ;
}
else
{
    for (i = -1 ; i >= p ; i--);
        pow *= 1/n ;
}

return pow;
}
```

the programs intent is clear the problem is when I input some test cases the output is wrong
like 
(5 2) 
the output should be 25 but I get 5
(5 6)
the output should be 15625 but i get 5

after examining this problem with gdb I found that instead of initializing i to 1 it is initialized to 3 for no obvious reason and with the second input i is initialized to 7
i want to know why

I'm using gcc.

Comment: Where is it initialized to 3?

Comment: [First rule of programming: it's always your fault.](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/)

Comment: Use a decent editor that indents your code automatically and you'll spot the mistake easily.

Comment: OT: Instead of doing `pow *= 1/n;` it might be more straight forward to do: `pow /= n;`

Comment: @X.L.Ant: Not always: once there was a bug in LLVM which caused the result of memory read operations on the process you were debugging to be false. You thought that your code misbehaves at a certain point, because the variable you were looking at had a wrong value. But in fact the value was correct, and LLVM just reported a wrong value. I lost tons of time on that bug...

Comment: @X.L.Ant yes that is at least form my Little experience ture

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux Of course. Read the post, the message is: start by assuming it's your fault (which it is, most of the time), and only dig further when you're sure it's not.

Comment: Always compile with *all warnings and debug info*, e.g. with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: Chronic inability to debug, count #001262846.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you blame the compiler, I would blame my eyes first you have an extra semicolon in both your for loops

```
for (i = 1 ; i <= p ; i++);
```

change it to

```
for (i = 1 ; i <= p ; i++)
```

Comment: Sure, but this should really be a close-vote as "simple typo".

Comment: as much as i'm extremly angry now for this mess but thanks

Comment: @Lockon2000: I bet this happened to each one of us one time ... even if it's been so long that the one or the other refuses to remember ... .. ;-)

Comment: @alk but this is very frustrating i'm now using c for nearly a year and this example was just a warm up so i'm really disappointed

Comment: @Lockon2000 I don't think you should worry about it, it just happens. It really makes you feel stupid, but it goes away.

Comment: "*... disappointed*" so you will remember this, and it will mosty likley not happen to you again. This is the simple process of learning and gaining (more and more) experiences ... - the really disappointing thing is that when your are really good, it's over ...

Comment: @iharob no i will read it now